# FSEvents: get monitored path inside fsevents_callback

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, fsevents

My application has few objects which watch for certain changes in few folders. FSEvents library is used.

The problem is I don't see easy way to get monitored path(s) in some watchers in **fsevents_callback**. Maybe it's trivial, yet reference to **self** (where monitored path is stored) is not available in this callback and inside this callback is way too less information available to identify enclosing object.

```
void fsevents_callback(ConstFSEventStreamRef streamRef, void *clientCallBackInfo, size_t numEvents, NSArray *eventPaths, const FSEventStreamEventFlags eventFlags[], const
                       FSEventStreamEventId eventIds[]) {

  size_t i;
  for (i = 0; i < numEvents; ++i)
  {
    NSString *processedPath = [eventPaths objectAtIndex:i];
    {
      //if ([processedPath isEqualToString: path]) {
      void (^block)() = (__bridge void (^)())(clientCallBackInfo);
      block();
      //do something else & break }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: its not clear from your question what you are asking. can you post some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `FSEventStreamCopyPathsBeingWatched` function.

> Fetches the paths supplied when the stream was created via one of the
>   FSEventStreamCreate...() functions.

If you want self object inside call back function, you should pass self in clientCallBackInfo.

Comment: FSEventStreamCopyPathsBeingWatched solves this problem perfectly. Thanks for awesome hint!